Streamlit access to SSL files
Running as root works
If I run streamlit as root:
streamlit hello \
    --browser.serverAddress dharmatech.dev \
    --browser.serverPort 8502 \
    --server.sslCertFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dharmatech.dev/fullchain.pem \
    --server.sslKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dharmatech.dev/privkey.pem

it works fine and I can access the site at:
https://dharmatech.dev:8502/

Not running as root
Of course, I'd prefer not to run streamlit as root.
If I run it as a regular user, I get the following:
$ streamlit hello --browser.serverAddress dharmatech.dev --browser.serverPort 8502 --server.sslCertFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dharmatech.dev/fullchain.pem --server.sslKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dharmatech.dev/privkey.pem

Collecting usage statistics. To deactivate, set browser.gatherUsageStats to false.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dharmatech/python-environments/env-3.10-streamlit/bin/streamlit", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/dharmatech/python-environments/env-3.10-streamlit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dharmatech/python-environments/env-3.10-streamlit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/dharmatech/python-environments/env-3.10-streamlit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/dharmatech/python-environments/env-3.10-streamlit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/dharmatech/python-environments/env-3.10-streamlit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dharmatech/python-environments/env-3.10-streamlit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/web/cli.py", line 188, in main_hello
    _main_run(filename, flag_options=kwargs)
  File "/home/dharmatech/python-environments/env-3.10-streamlit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/web/cli.py", line 270, in _main_run
    bootstrap.run(file, is_hello, args, flag_options)
  File "/home/dharmatech/python-environments/env-3.10-streamlit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/web/bootstrap.py", line 405, in run
    asyncio.run(run_server())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/dharmatech/python-environments/env-3.10-streamlit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/web/bootstrap.py", line 393, in run_server
    await server.start()
  File "/home/dharmatech/python-environments/env-3.10-streamlit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/web/server/server.py", line 269, in start
    start_listening(app)
  File "/home/dharmatech/python-environments/env-3.10-streamlit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/web/server/server.py", line 118, in start_listening
    ssl_options = _get_ssl_options(cert_file, key_file)
  File "/home/dharmatech/python-environments/env-3.10-streamlit/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/web/server/server.py", line 143, in _get_ssl_options
    if not Path(cert_file).exists():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/pathlib.py", line 1290, in exists
    self.stat()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/pathlib.py", line 1097, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/letsencrypt/live/dharmatech.dev/fullchain.pem'

Question
So the issue is the regular user doesn't have access to the fullchain.pem and privkey.pem files.
What's the best practice for allowing streamlit access to these files without running as root?
Approach: change permissions
I could chmod the files and directories as appropriate. However, I've seen it mentioned that the letsencrypt files get the permissions reset periodically. So this doesn't seem like a sustainable approach.
Approach: renewal post hood
This answer:
https://serverfault.com/a/1085282/102828
mentions a script approach. However, I haven't seen any one else suggest this approach so I'm wondering if it's indeed the best practice here.

Set the permissions so the service can read the files.

Hey @GeraldSchneider ‍♂️. I updated the question to link to another answer that uses a script. He says he does this because the permissions revert occasionally. However, I haven't seen others mention this approach. So I'm wondering if it's indeed the best recommended practice.

Every good ACME client is able to run commands after each renewal. For Certbot, those can be placed in "hook" scripts at:
/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy/

Use that to create a script which either copies the privkey.pem file where appropriate, or sets the permissions on it to allow your account to access it, or both. (And then reloads/restarts the service, if that's needed to make it notice changes.)
#!/bin/sh

setfacl -m u:dharmauser:r $RENEWED_LINEAGE/{fullchain,privkey}.pem

# or this:
# chgrp ssl-cert $RENEWED_LINEAGE/{fullchain,privkey}.pem
# chmod g+r $RENEWED_LINEAGE/{fullchain,privkey}.pem

# or this:
# cp $RENEWED_LINEAGE/fullchain.pem ~streamlit/ssl.crt
# cp $RENEWED_LINEAGE/privkey.pem ~streamlit/ssl.key
# chown streamlit ~streamlit/ssl.{crt,key}
# chmod 0600 ~streamlit/ssl.{crt,key}

systemctl try-reload-or-restart foobar


For the entire /etc/letsencrypt/live/ directory, the best method depends on 1) what you're doing with the cert/key files and 2) what created the directory originally.

If the hook script copies the cert/key files to a separate configuration directory, then the original directory's permissions don't matter.

Otherwise, if the live directory was part of the Certbot package – and if your distribution's package manager likes to revert changes to directory permissions, then the easiest way is to use the same script to chmod it as well.

But some package managers also have ways to override the "packaged" file permissions, such as Debian's dpkg-statoverride.




Thanks for this answer! I also found this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/1085282/102828 Is using /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy now preferred over using `certbot renew --post-hook' as he mentions htere?

I find install extremely helpful to simplify cp+chown+chmod operations

That's two different questions: post-hooks vs deploy-hooks, and command-line options vs static /etc files. 2) Post hooks run once after the entire process; deploy hooks run separately for each certificate. Both can be used for this, just slightly differently. 1) Placing the script under renewal-hooks is easier – avoids issues if you forget to use the --xx-hook option, and especially your distribution already provides a certbot service/cronjob then it's much easier to just add the file in that location than to modify the distro-provided service to run a hook from your custom location.

(For example, in a deploy hook you have $RENEWAL_DOMAINS telling you which cert was just renewed right now, whereas in a post hook – as far as I know – you have no built-in way of knowing which certs were renewed in general (unless you manually fiddle with 'flag files' etc). That might matter if a service is slow to restart and you don't want it restarting every 2-3 days when completely unrelated renewals happen; that's easier to avoid with a deploy hook.)

If I add a script to renewal-hooks/deploy, is there a way to trigger it to test it out instead of waiting till the next renewal?

You can manually run it with the two Certbot environment variables specified (assuming your script uses them): env RENEWAL_DOMAINS="dharmatech.dev" RENEWED_LINEAGE="/etc/letsencrypt/live/dharmatech.dev" /etc/.../deploy/myscript. But if the script doesn't use the envvars and directly goes for specific paths (like the other example you found earlier), then just run it like normal.

Grawity... I'm so grateful for your help! If you have a paypal, mention it here and I'll buy you lunch.

At the very least, I had to give you thanks in the project README:  https://github.com/dharmatech/fed_net_liquidity_streamlit.py/tree/main

Got it working in prod: https://dharmatech.dev:8501/fed-net-liquidity/
